# bundle install error - ruby_dep-1.5.0 requires ruby version >= 2.2.5 but I have version 3.0.1p64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I used to work in a project with a Ubuntu machine flawlessly.
After some time, I decided to hop into Fedora and now that I've setup everything, I was going to continue the project but when I run `bundle install` I get the following:

```
➜ bundle install
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /usr/bin
  /usr/share/gems
  /usr/share/gems/build_info
  /usr/share/gems/bundler
  /usr/share/gems/cache
  /usr/share/gems/doc
  /usr/share/gems/extensions
  /usr/share/gems/gems
  /usr/share/gems/plugins
  /usr/share/gems/specifications
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies....
ruby_dep-1.5.0 requires ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 3.0.1p64
```

Clearly my Ruby version requirement is met.
Should I downgrade it so I could continue?
If so, how to properly do it without rvm or rbenv?

I was able to find 2 lines with `ruby_dep` on Gemfile.lock and I'm not quite sure how to proceed. The first result is nested and the other isn't:

```
listen (3.1.5)
  rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
  rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
  ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
...
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
```

Should I keep one or change the version of both? I couldn't find `ruby_dep` anywhere else besides Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 27):

I ran into the same issue.

One method is to delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`

This deletes all existing references to `ruby_dep` and gives you a fresh install of your gems.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer

Comment: I don't think it's wise, at least on larger production codebases, to delete your `Gemfile.lock` since that can cause more discrepancies in other versions. Instead run `bundle update ruby_dep listen ... {any other packages it complains about`

Comment: agreed, this definitely caused issues for me, because it may upgrade other gems to versions with breaking changes, if they aren't version restricted in the `Gemfile`.  Of course, you could say this is a `Gemfile` config issue, but I think this can come up with older production apps that you've inherited, and not aware of potential issues like this.

Answer (score 12):

Deleting the whole `Gemfile.lock` file (as suggested in another answer) might not be the best idea.

First, simply try to update the `ruby_dep` in your dependencies:

```
bundle update ruby_dep
```

Comment: This worked for me using the advice on a previous answer comment from @Jack Kinsella.  I ran `bundle update ruby_dep listen` which resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

When it says it requires sudo to install gems, it's because you're using the system Ruby (Ruby that your OS uses), and it's not a good idea to alter that.

Install a different version of Ruby and confirm it's set to that, then bundle.

Answer (score 0):

## Step-by-step

1. Add **webrick** gem to **gemfile**
2. Remove specific jekyll version number from gemfile. Leave only `gem "jekyll"`
3. Run `bundler`
4. Run `bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload`

Answer (score -3):

Pay attention to `~> 2.2`, it means 2.x, but not 3. Read more here https://bundler.io/gemfile.html

Comment: I believe the author is trying to use a newer version of Ruby and the`requires ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2` error is likely outdated from his previous Ruby 2.x gemset